# How to differently write reinterpret_cast<>

Tags: c++

I have a lot of `reinterpret_cast`s in my code. Can I do something like this

```
using c = reinterpret_cast<T*>
```

where `T` is a template arg. So it would look like this

```
std::uninitialized_move(c(temp)....)
```

Here is an example:

```
char* new_buffer_ = new char[size_* sizeof(T) * 2];
std::uninitialized_move(reinterpret_cast<T*>(buffer_), 
                        reinterpret_cast<T*>(buffer_) + size_,
                        reinterpret_cast<T*>(new_buffer_));
```

Comment: Can we see a minimal example of you usage of `reinterpret_cast`?  It's very easy to have undefined behavior when using `reinterpret_cast` as only certain casts are actually allowed.

Comment: @1233456 you can make an `std::array<T, size_ * 2>` and some function templates for converting it into `std::array<std::uint8_t, size_* sizeof(T) * 2>` for you

Comment: [Pro Tip] Don't use `new char[size_* sizeof(T) * 2]` to create a buffer of objects.  It's not guaranteed to have the alignment `T` needs.  Use either `new alignas(alignof(T)) char[size_* sizeof(T) * 2] or `new std::aligned_storage<T>[2]`.

Comment: sorry guys, i am just new here, have been coding for 1 year

Comment: So what i am about, if i can assign reinterpret_cast<T*> to "cast" and then instead of writing everywhere reinterpret_cast<T*> i would use cast(...)

Comment: What you want to do is possible in lots of ways: you can write a `cast` function or lambda or macro: `#define cast(X) reinterpret_cast<T*>(X)` (beware though: `T` will be whatever `T` is at the point of use, not where the macro is defined).  That said, in most code it's very rare to use `reinterpret_cast`, and error-prone, so it's generally best to leave it verbose and standing out visually, so people are thinking about the risks when they maintain that code.  Another option is to cast the returned pointer from `new` to `T*` early - get the type right as soon as possible.

Comment: Oh, ok, it's nice to hear that from an experienced people. To me it looks terrible if i have 10 lines straight each under each of reinterpret_cast

Comment: By the way, you guys implement algorithms if i give you steps or something?

Comment: If you are using `reinterpret_cast` that much then you're either implementing a container (of which there are plenty in the standard library) or you're thinking about the problem in a very wrong way. What is the _actual goal_ you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: that's why i am moving from buffer_

Comment: There are ways to do it, but all this has the feel of a programmer thinking in terms of assembly or C, when C++ probably has a better, safer, easier way to do whatever the bigger picture actually needs.

Comment: The best reinterpret_cast is reinterpret_cast you don't use.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is a big, very dangerous hammer.  Avoid if at all possible.  If you haven't been programming C++ for 4 years (day in and day out), don't use it at all, because you'll use it wrong.

Comment: "_you guys implement algorithms if i give you steps or something?_" - No, but you'll probably get help if you create a new question where you show your code in which you've tried to implement the algorithm yourself.

Comment: Minor detail: You can remove one `reinterpret_cast` by using `uninitialized_move_n` instead.

Comment: @TonyDelroy You would have to pass `T` as another macro parameter, eg: `#define cast(T, X) reinterpret_cast<T*>(X)` ... `std::uninitialized_move(cast(T, buffer_), cast(T, buffer_) + size_, cast(T, new_buffer_));` I would suggest using a template function instead: `template <typename To, typename From> To* cast(From *X) { return reinterpret_cast<To*>(X); }` ... `std::uninitialized_move(cast<T*>(buffer_), cast<T*>(buffer_) + size_, cast<T*>(new_buffer_));`

Comment: Why are you doing all this instead of using a [`std::vector<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Because `std::vector` puts things on the heap.  https://github.com/Ambeco/SmallContainers/blob/master/SmallContainers/small_vector.h#L261

Comment: @MooingDuck So does a new-expression, most likely.

Comment: @NathanOliver that should be either `std::aligned_storage<T>::type` or `std::aligned_storage_t<T>`. I remember tripping up on that one before :)

Comment: @NathanOliver `It's not guaranteed to have the alignment T needs.` only if the alignment requirement is stricter than alignment of max_align_t. Aligned new is only needed for over aligned types.

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to save typing without any change in functionality, you can write:

```
template<typename T>
static T* c(char *p) { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(p); }
```

or to avoid scope pollution,

```
template<typename T>
auto c = [](char *p) { return reinterpret_cast<T *>(p); };
```

But, as stressed in comments, there is likely a better way to design your code in order to not need all of these casts in the first place.